# Prism - Shell as UserControl and initialize bootstrapper from WPF Application

Tags: wpf, shell, user-controls, prism, bootstrapper

I have developed a Prism WPF application (from now on named PrismWpfApp).
Now I want to run this application from another WPF Application (from now on named Simulator) and show the shell of the PrismWpfApp into a UserControl of the MainWindow of the Simulator.

The Simulator MainWindow looks as this:

```
<Window x:Class="Simulator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Simulator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <UserControl Name="SimulatorMainUserControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

From the Simulator I run the PrismWpfApp as follows:

```
namespace Simulator
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();

        }
    }
}
```

My bootstrapper looks as follows:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    public Shell shell;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {

    }
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        BuildContainer();

        // Use the container to create an instance of the shell.
        this.shell = this.Container.TryResolve<Shell>();
        return this.shell;
    }

    private void BuildContainer()
    {
        var assemblyLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
        path = Path.Combine(path, "KNXPM.db3");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Data.RepositoryBase<>), new InjectionConstructor(path));
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepositoryInitializer), typeof(Data.RepositoryInitializer), new InjectionConstructor(path));
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IShell), this.Shell, WithLifetime.PerThread(typeof(IShell)));

        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    public PrismKnxPmpApp.Views.Shell GetShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(ToolBar), Container.Resolve<ToolBarRegionAdapter>());
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(ToolBarTray), Container.Resolve<ToolBarTrayRegionAdapter>());
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(StackPanel), Container.Resolve<StackPanelRegionAdapter>());
        return mappings;
    }
}
```

However, since the Shell is a Window, when I execute the Simulator I get two Windows: one for the Simulator and one for the PrismWpfApp. I am stuck in displaying the Shell of the PrismWpfApp into the Simulator.

This is my Shell:

```
<metro:MetroWindow x:Class="PrismKnxPmpApp.Views.Shell"               
                   xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"                      
                   >
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsLocked="True" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource MainToolBarTrayStyle}">
                <ToolBar x:Name="NavigationItemsControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainNavigationRegion" Style="{StaticResource MainToolBarStyle}" >                              
                </ToolBar>
            </ToolBarTray>

            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContentRegion" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>                         
    </Grid>
</metro:MetroWindow>
```

I am using Prism 6, Unity 4, .NET framework 4.5.2

Comment: What is a "plugin"? And on a side note, "method not found" hints at messed up references. How do you deploy?

Comment: Hi @Haukinger. By plugin I mean an extension for a 3rd party software. My plugin has a reference to my prism application, so I don't know what can be wrong in the references there.

Comment: Which third party app? Is it a command line tool or a win forms app or a wpf app or some c++ tool or an excel addin or an azure service or or or...? I think that's rather important to know to answer...

Comment: Hi @Haukinger . The 3rd party is a C++ application.

Comment: How does it create your app? How does it start it? How do the two interact? Does it run on windows or unix? As of now, we could just guess what's your problem... how do you expect us to do that if you, with all the information, have no idea?

Comment: You are right @Haukinger. I didn't give a lot of context. In order to explain myself better, I'm going to edit the question and create a Simulator WPF Application from which I will want to run another Prism Application and put the shell of the prism application inside a UserControl of my Simulator.